# How to simplify this expression $(t - \lambda)^3 - 10\cdot(t - \lambda)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression (equation):

$$(t - \lambda)^3 - 10\cdot(t - \lambda) = 0$$

Which can be expanded to:

$$t^3 +3t\lambda^2 - 3t^2\lambda -\lambda^3 - 10t + 10 \lambda = 0$$

Now, what I need is to find the values of $t$ for which $\lambda > 0$, but this is really a huge expression for me and I am not managing to do it.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $t-\lambda$ as a unique entity:
$$
(t-\lambda)\bigl((t-\lambda)^2-10\bigr)=0
$$
which becomes
$$
(t-\lambda)(t-\lambda-\sqrt{10})(t-\lambda+\sqrt{10})=0
$$

Comment: @Xenomorph If you want that all roots are positive, you can observe that the least one is $t-\sqrt{10}$, so you need $t>\sqrt{10}$. Right.